# Removing string before open parenthesis using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have an expression Nvl(cost,Sum(cost1))
i need to remove string before paranthesis i.e NVl and Sum in this case

```
        String functions=externalFormat.replaceAll("\\([^\\(]*\\)", "");
```

Input Nvl(cost,Sum(Cost1)
Output cost,cost1

Comment: Although not a neat way but you can use `\w+\(|\)` and replace with empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String externalFormat="Nvl(cost,Sum(Cost1)";
        String functions=externalFormat.replaceAll("\\w+\\(|\\)", "");
        System.out.println(functions.toLowerCase());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use capture groups (ie, if you CAN use capture groups, `(\w*?)\(` will capture the text you need to replace in the first group)

You could use a positive look-ahead to only capture word characters (letter or number) that appear before an open bracket:

```
\w*(?=\()
```

You could even add optional white space characters in case of things like: `Nvl1 (cost,Sum (cost1))` by including them before the look-ahead: -

```
\w*\s*(?=\()
```

Hope this helps solve your problem.